# MySqlDataReader always Returning False even though data is there In Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datareader

Hii Guys !!!
             I made one C# class and one handler in Asp.net..In My C# file I made a function which is as Below:

```
public MySqlDataReader Consulta(String sql){

    String error="";

    try 
    {

        string connectionString = "Server=*****;Port=3306;Database=db;UID=*****;Pwd=****;pooling=false";
        MySqlConnection conn;
        conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();

        //string s = "select empid,empname,authcode from authcode";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql,conn);

        //cmd.CommandText = s;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        rs =cmd.ExecuteReader();

        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            //error = e.getMessage();
        }

        return (rs);
}
```

In My handler File i am calling this function here is my code...

```
MySqldataReader rs = conexiondb.Consulta(strQuery);

total = conexiondb.countRec("price", "processeddata_table");

string json;
json = json + "{\n";
json = json + " \"page\":\""+intpage+"\",\n";
json = json + "\"total\":"+total_pages+",\n";
json = json + "\"records\":"+total+",\n";
json = json + "\"rows\": [";
rc =false;

while(rs.Read()){

    if(rc){
        json = json + ",";
    }
    json = json + "\n{";
    json = json + "\"price\":\"" + Convert.ToInt32(rs["price"]) + "\",";
    json = json + "\"cell\":[" + Convert.ToInt32(rs["price"]) + "";
    json = json + ",\"" + Convert.ToString(rs["username"]) + "\"";
    json = json + ",\"" + Convert.ToString(rs["ordinal"]) + "\"";
    json = json + ",\"" + Convert.ToString(rs["authcode"]) + "\"";
    json = json + ",\"" + Convert.ToString(rs["extension"]) + "\"";
    json = json + ",\"" + Convert.ToString(rs["trunk"]) + "\"";
    json = json + ",\"" + Convert.ToString(rs["dialnumber"]) + "\"";
    json = json + ",\"" + Convert.ToString(rs["dialdate"]) + "\"";
    json = json + ",\"" + Convert.ToString(rs["dialtime"]) + "\"";
    json = json + ",\"" + Convert.ToString(rs["duration"]) + "\"";
    json = json + ",\"" + Convert.ToString(rs["destination"]) + "\"";
    json = json + ",\"" + Convert.ToString(rs["price"]) + "\"";
    json = json + ",\"" + Convert.ToString(rs["toc"]) + "\"]";
    json = json + "}";

    rc=true;
}
json = json +"]\n";

json = json +"}";

HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(json);
```

But datareader is not reading the records it is always Returning false.Plz guys Help me to 
sort the problem .

Comment: Well you should sort out your exception handling, for one thing. You won't be able to tell if an exception is being thrown, because you completely swallow *all* exceptions...

Comment: If I were you I'd put a breakpoint in the method  Consulta  and see if any exceptions are gotten there since you have a catch block that doesn't notify you if an exception occurs.

Comment: You should also try and make your code a little readable.

Comment: Define "data is there". How did you verify it? What is your `strQuery`?

Comment: never ever publish your your connection string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least two issues
 first one is that you are swallowing any exceptions. This probably causes your problem. If there was an exception it's very likely that you can't read from the reader which would result in your while loop never executing. There's a reason why having an empty catch is a warning

Secondly your are trying to execute both an NonQuery (an command that does not query data) and a query with the same reader. Whether this would cause an exception I don't know but at least there's no reason to do both. You could remove both issues

```
public MySqlDataReader Consulta(String sql){
            string connectionString = "Server=***;Port=3306;Database=****;UID=***;Pwd=****;pooling=false";
   var conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
   conn.Open();

   var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql,conn);
   var rs =cmd.ExecuteReader();
   return (rs);
}
```

Comment: I don't think `ExecuteNonQuery` will throw an exception for a `SELECT` query - it just returns the number of rows affected (which would be 0 for a `SELECT`) instead of giving you a mechanism to iterate the results.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line of code 
`cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

EDIT: [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) is used for DML statements such as `UPDATE`, `INSERT`.

Read comments by @Jon on exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your problem stems from this local variable

```
MySqlConnection conn;
```

when you exit from the method Consulta this variable get destroyed and the underlying connection is closed. This will render your MySqlDataReader unusable because it requires an open connection

I will refactor your code removing the call to Consulta in this way:

```
string sql = "your SELECT command here";
string connectionString = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=projecttt;" +
                         "UID=root;Pwd=techsoft;pooling=false";

using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
     conn.Open();
     using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql,conn))
     {
          using(MySqlDataReader rs =cmd.ExecuteReader())
          {
               total = conexiondb.countRec("price", "processeddata_table");

               string json;
               json = json + "{\n";
               json = json + " \"page\":\""+intpage+"\",\n";
               json = json + "\"total\":"+total_pages+",\n";
               json = json + "\"records\":"+total+",\n";
               json = json + "\"rows\": [";
               rc =false;
               while(rs.Read())
               {
                  .....
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: Thnx steve but it is not happening with this also

Comment: Well, could you show the sql command issued? AND REMOVE the empty catch clause. Don't suppress anything that could give you an hint on what is going wrong here.

Comment: The connection would not get destroyed - The Reader would have a reverence to either the command (which would have a reference to the connection) or the connection itself.